# Delete all data from a PostGIS topology

Tags: postgis, postgis-2.0, topology

I need to delete everything (faces, nodes, edges, anything I'm not thinking of) from a PostGIS topology, but I want to keep my database schema (schemas, tables, columns, sequences, etc.) intact. Is there a simple way to do that? If not, what elements do I need to delete and what functions/queries would I use to delete them?

Comment: pg_dump with schema only http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/app-pgdump.html or copy your existing database and truncate all tables http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2829158/truncating-all-tables-in-a-postgres-database

Comment: @Mapperz I'm looking into fiddling with the underlying topology tables manually, but I've noticed that at least the `face` table has a row in it when you create a new topology. Since the topology tables are something PostGIS is supposed to manage for me, I'm a bit cautious about just truncating them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this might do the trick. Let's say you created your topology like this:

```
SELECT topology.CreateTopology('my_topo', 4326, 0.01);
SELECT topology.AddTopoGeometryColumn('my_topo', 'my_layer', 'topogeom', 'MULTIPOLYGON');
```

where `my_layer` is an existing table.

1. Remove any data from tables with a `TopoGeometry` column using this topology.

   ```
   DELETE FROM my_layer;
   ```

   Do this for each table you added a column to.
2. Delete any "topology geometries" by clearing out the `relation` table.

   ```
   DELETE FROM my_topo.relation;
   ```
3. Remove all edges.

   ```
   SELECT ST_RemEdgeModFace('my_topo', edge_id) FROM my_topo.edge_data;
   ```

   I don't think it matters which `ST_RemEdge*Face` function you used. I chose this one since it won't create new ones, which seemed like unnecessary overhead. Note that this step will fail if any geometries (represented in `relation`) cannot be represented after deleting an edge; that's why you have to clear `relation` first.
4. Remove all nodes.

   ```
   SELECT ST_RemoveIsoNode('my_topo', node_id) FROM my_topo.node;
   ```

   We can get away with this since after removing all edges, the nodes are all isolated.

Note that we didn't have to delete any faces manually. I advise against trying to do so; I noticed that the `face` table in the topology has a row initially, even thought it doesn't count that row as a face when summarizing the topology.

Following this, our topology appears to be empty:

```
dbname=# SELECT TopologySummary ('my_topo');
                       topologysummary
-------------------------------------------------------------
 Topology temp_overlay_topo (21), SRID 4326, precision 0.01+
 0 nodes, 0 edges, 0 faces, 0 topogeoms in 0 layers         +
 Layer 1, type Polygonal (3), 0 topogeoms                   +
  Deploy: my_layer.topogeom                +

(1 row)
```

I'm pretty new to topologies. I welcome any feedback, suggestions, or corrections.